# Clicking in input button not functioning as expected

Tags: puppeteer

I have the following code:

```
<li id="ecf43e6a-0a99-4b88-9927-7f6b681bc18d" class="checked">
        <input type="button">
        <span>Green</span>
      </li>
```

I'm trying to click on the button by doing this.

```
const btnWrap = await page.$('#ecf43e6a-0a99-4b88-9927-7f6b681bc18d');
await btnWrap.$eval('input', el => el.click());
```

I'm getting an error on this any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Can you share the error please? As your script is valid I suspect the element is rendered a bit later than the other elements of the page so it requires an extra waitFor_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your script works just fine.

You may need to wait for the element to be appeared:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('#ecf43e6a-0a99-4b88-9927-7f6b681bc18d')
```

I think that will do the job as well:

```js
await page.$eval('#ecf43e6a-0a99-4b88-9927-7f6b681bc18d > input', el => el.click());
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer but on my end the problem was the id changes on each reload.  Technically as you said the element doesn't appear.  Thank you!